# Generate dates based on a list of hours and minutes

Tags: python

I have this list of hours and minutes. I want to modify the list so each element of the list has a date after it.

```
['09:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', '16:00', '16:20', '17:00', '18:00', '20:00', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '00:00', '01:00', '03:00', '04:00', '07:00', '09:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '18:00']
```

In order to get the relevant date for each hour, I tried to calculate the time, but the result isn't what I want.

```
for start in times:
     now = datetime.today().strftime('%Y %m %d')
     first_elem= (datetime.strptime(times[0],'%H:%M')  - timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%H:%M')
     tit = datetime.strptime(start,'%H:%M')
     m=tit.strftime('%M')
     h=tit.strftime('%H')
     b = datetime.strptime(now+' '+first_elem,'%Y %m %d %H:%M').strftime('%Y %m %d %H:%M')
     a = datetime.strptime(b,'%Y %m %d %H:%M')
     a += timedelta(hours=int(h),minutes=int(m))
     print(a)
```

This is the output I get:

```
2020-05-05 17:00:00
2020-05-05 19:00:00
2020-05-05 20:00:00
2020-05-05 21:00:00
2020-05-05 23:00:00
2020-05-06 00:00:00
2020-05-06 00:20:00
2020-05-06 01:00:00
2020-05-06 02:00:00
2020-05-06 04:00:00
2020-05-06 06:00:00
2020-05-06 06:30:00
2020-05-06 07:00:00
2020-05-05 08:00:00
2020-05-05 09:00:00
2020-05-05 11:00:00
2020-05-05 12:00:00
2020-05-05 15:00:00
2020-05-05 17:00:00
2020-05-05 19:00:00
2020-05-05 20:00:00
2020-05-05 21:00:00
2020-05-05 23:00:00
2020-05-06 00:00:00
2020-05-06 00:30:00
2020-05-06 01:00:00
2020-05-06 02:00:00
```

But I want the date to increment every time the hours reset overnight. What I want to see is the date increment as displayed here:

```
2020-05-05 09:00:00
2020-05-05 11:00:00
2020-05-05 12:00:00
2020-05-05 13:00:00
2020-05-05 15:00:00
2020-05-05 16:00:00
2020-05-05 16:20:00
2020-05-05 17:00:00
2020-05-05 18:00:00
2020-05-05 20:00:00
2020-05-05 22:00:00
2020-05-05 22:30:00
2020-05-05 23:00:00
2020-05-06 00:00:00
2020-05-06 01:00:00
2020-05-06 03:00:00
2020-05-06 04:00:00
```

Comment: So the issue is that the days remain the same?

Comment: Yeah that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

data = ['09:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', '16:00', '16:20', '17:00', '18:00', '20:00', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '00:00', '01:00', '03:00', '04:00', '07:00', '09:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '18:00']
today = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) 
last_hr = 0
for d in data:
    h, m = map(int, d.split(":"))
    if last_hr > h:
        today = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)    #Increment date if last hour greater than current hr.

    last_hr = h
    print(today + datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m))
```

**Output:**

```
2020-05-05 09:00:00
2020-05-05 11:00:00
2020-05-05 12:00:00
2020-05-05 13:00:00
2020-05-05 15:00:00
2020-05-05 16:00:00
2020-05-05 16:20:00
2020-05-05 17:00:00
2020-05-05 18:00:00
2020-05-05 20:00:00
2020-05-05 22:00:00
2020-05-05 22:30:00
2020-05-05 23:00:00
2020-05-06 00:00:00
2020-05-06 01:00:00
2020-05-06 03:00:00
2020-05-06 04:00:00
2020-05-06 07:00:00
2020-05-06 09:00:00
2020-05-06 11:00:00
2020-05-06 12:00:00
2020-05-06 13:00:00
2020-05-06 15:00:00
2020-05-06 16:00:00
2020-05-06 16:30:00
2020-05-06 17:00:00
2020-05-06 18:00:00
```

Comment: That's exactly the result i'm looking for, thanks .

Comment: Well done; this raises an issue, if more than 24 hours have past.